# Async tasks and Simple Injector Lifetime scopes

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I've got the following method which resolves an `IConsumeAsync` which returns a task.

```
private Task ConsumeMessageAsync<TMessage, TConsumer>(TMessage message)
    where TMessage : class
    where TConsumer : IConsumeAsync<TMessage>
{
    var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    var instance = (IConsumeAsync<TMessage>)container
        .GetInstance(typeof(TConsumer));

    instance
        .Consume(message)
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted && task.Exception != null)
            {
                tsc.SetException(task.Exception);
            }
            else
            {
                tsc.SetResult(null);
            }
        });

    return tsc.Task;
}
```

I need to wrap this with a lifetime scope ala

```
using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope()){
}
```

I've tried the following but it did not work 100%

```
var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();

var wrapper = ConsumeMessageAsync<TMessage, TConsumer>(message);
wrapper.ContinueWith(x => scope.Dispose());
wrapper.Start();
```

And I got the following error:

> Additional information: It is not safe to use a LifetimeScope instance
>   across threads. Make sure the complete operation that the lifetime
>   scope surrounds gets executed within the same thread and make sure
>   that the LifetimeScope instance gets disposed on the same thread as it
>   gets created. Dispose was called on thread with ManagedThreadId 27,
>   but was created on thread with id 21.

I'm not quite sure how to wrap an asynchronous task in .NET with using statements to tried a manual kind using an extra wrapper task to control the flow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the [AsyncScopedLifestyle](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#asyncscoped) instead. The `ThreadScopedLifestyle` (previously called `LifetimeScopeLifestyle`) creates a thread-specific scope, while the `AsyncScopedLifestyle` creates a scope that flows with the logical flow of control of asynchronous methods.

```cs
// using SimpleInjector.Lifestyles;

using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container)) {
    var service = container.GetInstance<ISomeService>();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steven! Massive help in the last few days.

Comment: Thank you for adding the using! I can't say how many times I spend more time trying to find the right one for the solution provided.